# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI flutter getconnect

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to use the [Get Connect](https://pub.dev/packages/get#getconnect) package to make an API call from my flutter application that totally depends on GetX .

Here is the code am using :

```dart
class OnBoardingProvider extends GetConnect {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    httpClient.baseUrl = 'https://www.my_domain_name.com/';
    httpClient.addRequestModifier((request) {
      request.headers['lang'] = Get.locale.languageCode;
      return request;
    });
    if (UserModelProvider().checkForLogin()) {
      httpClient.addAuthenticator((request) {
        String token = UserModelProvider().getToken();
        request.headers['Authorization'] = "Token $token";
        return request;
      });
    }
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getOnBoarding() async {
    final response = await get('static-pages/api/on_boarding/');
    return response.body;
  }
```

but it keeps showing me the error

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI static-pages/api/on_boarding/
```

that means the line `httpClient.baseUrl = ...` didn't affect the code .. or maybe am calling it the wrong way !!

**UPDATE**

am calling the instance of `OnBoardingProvider` this way when I call the function :

```dart
    OnBoardingProvider().getOnBoarding().then((value) {
      print(value.body);
    });
```

Comment: It might be because of onInit() not getting called hence baseUrl not getting initialised. Can you add about how your are creating instance of class OnBoardingProvider ?

Comment: @SahilHariyani added it to the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onInit` is not getting called, that's why baseUrl didn't get initialised.

The method 'onInit' is called when you inject the dependency using Get.put(Controller()); into the widget tree.

So,

```
OnBoardingProvider onBoardingProvider = Get.put(onBoardingProvider());

 onBoardingProvider.getOnBoarding().then((value) {
      print(value.body);
    });
```

More about [depenceny injection in GetX](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-getx-ecosystem-dependency-injection-8e763d0ec6b9) and [Get Connect](https://tayolakunle.medium.com/network-request-with-getconnect-in-flutter-4d7c5d7c0309)